# "Could not inherit file classes/multilib_script.bbclass" during Yocto Bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm trying Yocto Bitbake using "Rocko", but encountered the error below:

```
"Could not inherit file classes/multilib_script.bbclass"
```

I can see the description to inherit "multilib_script" in certain recipe indeed. But I was not able to find out which layer should be cloned and added as bblayer in "Rocko" version.

**bblayers.conf**

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-poky \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
"
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bbclass file is part of the main poky metadata layer which you have already included.

As can be seen from http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes?h=rocko the classes/multilib_script.bbclass file isn't present in the rocko branch.

It is present in a later release, e.g. thud http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes?h=thud and any other releases beyond that.

To use a recipe using that script, you'd either have to backport the class or use a later release where it is present.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! I'll consider upgrade my environment.